# Allow leading zeros in a LIKE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query which includes the line:

```
WHERE
   [TraceableItem].[IdentificationNo] LIKE N'015933%'
```

I would like this to match the following numbers:

> 015933
>
> 00015933
>
> 000000000015933

But not allow any non-zero characters. How could I do this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. 

Should I add that as a tag?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is an IDE, not a DBMS.

Comment: What version? You could possibly `TRY_CAST` as INT first.

Comment: Sorry, really not familiar with SQL. Failed the module in uni :P 

@JacobH not sure on version, sorry. I'll give that a go and report back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
--Some test data
DECLARE @sample TABLE
(
    number_as_string VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO @sample
VALUES
    ('015933')          -- okay
    ,('00015933')       -- okay
    ,('000000000015933')-- okay
    ,(' 00015933')      -- dont return as this doesnt start with a 0
    ,('25')             -- dont return wrong number
    ,('string')         -- dont return as its a string
    ,('st15933')        -- dont return as it starts with a string.
    ,('001000015933')   -- dont return as this is the number 1000015933

SELECT
    *
FROM 
    @sample as s
WHERE
    --only consider rows that are a number
    --stops CONVERT exception being thrown on lines that do no convert
    ISNUMERIC(s.number_as_string) = 1
    AND
    --Convert to INT wipes out the leading 0's, but also spaces
    CONVERT(INT,s.number_as_string) LIKE '15933%'
    AND
    --must start with a number, i.e. check it doesn't start with a space.
    --LEFT(s.number_as_string,1) NOT LIKE '[^0-9]'
    --This version is easier to read as its not a double NOT logic like the version above
    --Thanks to @Robert Kock
    LEFT(s.number_as_string,1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
```

Gives the result

```
number_as_string
----------------
015933
00015933
000000000015933
```

Comment: Consider adding "001000015933" to your example, poisted by Harry Adams in a comment to another answer.  It works correctly in your case.

Comment: Great answer. Maybe the last condition could be changed into `LEFT(s.number_as_string,1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'`. Might be a little more performant

Comment: Given this a test with a few more example cases and it works perfectly; thank you very much :-)

Comment: @pwilcox thanks I have added this to the set of tests.

Comment: @Harry - no worries

Comment: @RobertKock that is much easier to read as its doesn't use double negative logic. I have amended the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to first convert to int and back to string as suggested by Neeraj Agarwal.  But then take the left five characters and compare for exact equality to '15933'

```
where '15933' = left(convert(varchar(50),convert(int, 
          TraceableItem.IdentificationNo
      )),5)
```

You can see it at work in the sample below, where it captures everything you desire and a little more, but doesn't capture the case presented by Harry Adams in the comments to Neeraj.

```
select  *
from    (values 
           ('015933'),
           ('00015933'),
           ('000000000015933'),
           ('0001593399'),
           ('15933'),
           ('001000015933')
        ) vals (v)
where   '15933' = left(convert(varchar(50),convert(int, v)),5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like converting to a number for this purpose.  But one method is to "trim" the leading zeros away.  For an exact match:

```
where replace(ltrim(replace([TraceableItem].[IdentificationNo], '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') = '15933'
```

For `LIKE:`

```
where replace(ltrim(replace([TraceableItem].[IdentificationNo], '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') LIKE '15933%'
```

You can also express this with `LIKE`/`NOT LIKE`:

```
where TraceableItem].[IdentificationNo] like '%15933%' and
      TraceableItem].[IdentificationNo] not like '%[^0]%15933%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cast to convert to an int and back to a character string provided the string consists of digits only, e.g.:

```
select cast(cast("00015933" as int) as varchar(24))
```

Comment: Wouldn't this then match with, say, "001000015933"? Which would be a non-valid match